# What is the mechanism of hydroperoxide reduction by bisulfite?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism, experimental-chemistry

I am using bisulfite to quench allylic hydroperoxide products from a singlet oxygen ene reaction, to the corresponding alcohols. What is known about the mechanism of this reaction, and in particular could it involve an alkyl peroxysulfate ($\ce{R-O-O-SO3H}$)?

Comment: I doubt there's much hard data on peroxide/sulphur redox class. There are various mechanisms postulated, but not analysed in depth.